# useFetch in Nuxt3 keeping cached data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am facing the following issue with nuxt3.

- the dynamic page `[slug].vue` loads the initial slug's data correctly
- when I move away from the page and come back, the new data is not loaded, instead it still shows the old data.
- If I refresh the said page with old data, it works ok.

This seems to be happening because the new slug's api call was never made.

My `[slug.vue]` file looks like:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
const route = useRoute();

const slug = ref(String(route.params.slug));
console.log(slug.value);
const apicall = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${slug.value}`;
const { data: article } = await useFetch(
  `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${slug.value}`
);
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to Home</NuxtLink>
    <pre>
      {{ `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${slug}` }}
      {{ route.params.slug }}
      {{ article }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

The entire setup can be seen on stackblitz at: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mkgfrw?file=pages%2F[slug].vue,pages%2Findex.vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mkgfrw?file=pages%2F%5Bslug%5D.vue,pages%2Findex.vue)

Comment: Hm, there is maybe this `useFetch(() => 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/${slug.value}' )` or using a `refresh` option. Not sure about which one exactly. Check the API in the documentation to be sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, and checking the documentation here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/data-fetching/#refreshing-data I tried the following code which worked

```
const { data: article, refresh } = await useFetch(
  `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${slug.value}`
);

watchEffect(() => {
  refresh();
});
```

working example here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mkgfrw?file=pages%2F[slug].vue,app.vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mkgfrw?file=pages%2F%5Bslug%5D.vue,app.vue)

Comment: I was just about to say thanks and improvements to the answer are more than welcome. Feel free to post as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Your stackblitz did not work and gave me a 404 page not found '/'.

I think what you should try to do is using router-view component
and import {useRoute} from 'vue-router';

So useRoute updates the router-view and you can acces params, thats what solved it for me when i encountered the problem.

good luck

Comment: stackblitz link seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while fetching blogs using queryContent. Here's how I resolved it by defining a unique id that changes based on your data.

```
const route = useRoute().params
const slug = ref(route.slug)

const { data: blog } = await useAsyncData(`blog:${slug.value}`, () => queryContent('/blog').find())
```

Here `blog:${slug.value}` is the unique id we are supplying.

More info is available on the official [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#useasyncdata).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are no `initialCache` option. You can use `key: String(Math.random())` option so every request has different key and there are no cache.

Comment: Thanks. Do you maybe have an official reference as to why/when it was removed? Like a changelog or some nuxt team member announcing it?

Comment: There is a PR with comments https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/8885